# Remove standard delete button from list view page and add custom button there

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, custom-object, list-view

How to remove standard delete button and add custom delete button(LWC added to Quick action) here
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible in standard page but you can create a visualforce page to achieve this.